# Input text while python is running

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script, say script.run()
which is constantly running, aka nothing after that line is getting processed. Is there a way for me to read off my console while I have it running and process it with the same .py file?

Comment: so basically you want to have multiple threads?

Comment: "Is there a way for me to read off my console while I have it running and process it with the same .py file?" Am I understanding you right? Shouldn't you separate printing the console text from the background processes? Your python file should mainly do the processing, and simply print any related output while it's processing, instead of re-analyzing its printed output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing I was looking for is multi-threading, thanks, Julien Bernu!